ALLEXCEPT is interfering with Context filter
I'm a Tableau user and switching to PowerBI. I'm trying to migrate a dashboard from Tableau to PowerBI. I created a LoD filter that checks if the total working hours are greater than 1600 and count Employee ID. The numbers are not match as Tableau is using a contextual filter. The formula I created for total working hours is:
Global working hours= CALCULATE(SUM(table[working hours]), ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Emp Id]))>=1600

I tried using time range in ALLEXCEPT like this:
Global working hours= CALCULATE(SUM(table[working hours]), ALLEXCEPT(table, table[Emp Id], table[time range]))>=1600

But the result is blank, I know that the Power BI is calculating it on each time range. Which is cumulatively less than 1600. The problem is my time range is like 202201 where the syntax is year+weeknum. I'm using it as a filter range means between the range I need my EMP ID count.
So basically I want to know if there is a way I can calculate LOD in power BI without affecting my context filter in Power BI.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

We need to see your data model, some sample data and expected results in order to help.

I just have one table in the data model, all the columns are from that table only.
